# Default value for function as parameter

Tags: swift

```
func myFunc(f: () -> () ) {
    f()
}
```

Does it support adding a default value something like `f: () -> () = nil` so I can just call `myFunc()` without providing `f` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make the closure optional and then provide a `nil` default value for it.

Just make sure to safely unwrap the optional input argument (for example by using optional binding).

```
func myFunc(f: (() -> ())? = nil ) {
    if let f = f {
        f()
    }
}
```

Or you can use optional chaining if you don't want a different behaviour for a `nil` input argument than a non-nil one.

```
func myFunc(f: (() -> ())? = nil ) {
    f?()
}
```

Comment: You don't have to unwrap just `f?()` if it's nil it won't be executed

Comment: @Quver you're right, you can use optional chaining, but optional binding gives you the opportunity to specify a different behaviour for `nil` and `non-nil` input arguments.

Comment: Sure, you are right. I just think that optional chaining is fine for 90% cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but must be optional

```
func myFunc(f: (() -> ())? = nil ) {
    f?()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to [making the closure optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47382189/1630618), you can also just use an empty closure `{}` as the default:

```
func myFunc(f: (() -> ()) = {}) {
    f()
}
```

### Examples

```
myFunc()                       // does nothing
myFunc() { print("hello") }    // prints "hello"
myFunc(f: { print("bye") } )   // prints "bye"
```

Comment: It says I have to do this `@escaping (() -> ()) = {}`

Comment: Hmmm.  It doesn't for me.  I assume yours is more complex than this simple example.

Comment: Executing empty closure is not sufficient

Comment: @Quver, why not?  What is the problem with this solution?